# Perl script - tables created in real time in terminal output

Tags: perl

My script prints data on separate lines in terminal output, it looks like this:

```
Name: Paul Surname: Doe Age:34
Name: Paulo Surname: Doeson Age:28 
Name: Paulinho Surname: Docsone Age:5
Name: Paulmen Surname: Doee Age:12
Name: Paulchen Surname: Dooe Age:31
```

And I would like all data to be divided into columns and displayed equally in bars, as below:

```
Name: Paul     Surname: Doe     Age:34
Name: Paulo    Surname: Doeson  Age:28
Name: Paulinho Surname: Docsone Age:5 
Name: Paulmen  Surname: Doee    Age:12 
Name: Paulchen Surname: Dooe    Age:31
```

I note that the output can not be buffered or stored. I would like to achieve this in real time while running the script. Are there any tricks to achieve this? Something like specifying the width of a cell in an HTML table?

**EDIT**
Really EXAMPLE code:

```
@arr = q(Name: Paul Surname: Doe Age:34, Name: Paulo Surname: Doeson Age:28, Name: Paulinho Surname: Docsone Age:5, Name: Paulmen Surname: Doee Age:12, Name: Paulchen Surname: Dooe Age:31);

foreach (@arr) {
  # here should be our trick to creating columns
  print $_ # should be print element in columns (without buffering). print now, not after loop end. 
}
```

Comment: There seems to be plenty of table/text formatting modules on CPAN. See for example [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table)

Comment: Its work in real time? How?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *"real time"*. Please show the code you are working on. You may edit your question to include more information

Comment: Unless you can go through the data before printing it out and working out the maximum column sizes, I can't see how you could do this.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I edited. Is clear now? I want print each element before loop is ends.

Comment: @ChrisTurner can I specify the width of the columns at all?

Comment: If you know the size you want for each column (which seems contradictory with your "real time" though), you could use `printf` with `%-XXs` (where `XX` is replaced by the length of your column). See [`perldoc -f sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes into my mind are [Perl formats](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). It's built-in and give's you a whole bunch of means for formatting output. Have a look at it.

Comment: Its available from perl 5.26 and above?

Comment: The ***Perl 5*** module [`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) is a huge improvement over Perl 5's native format facility.

Comment: @J. Doe: I don't know an exact version number. But it's in Perl since ages. So any recent implementation should work.